# Why does UITextView set clipsToBounds to true by default?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uikit, uitextview

For a `UITextView`, why is `clipsToBounds` set to `true` by default?

Is it OK to set it to `false` if I want to add to my `UITextView` a subview whose frame extends beyond the visible bounds of my `UITextView`? I've set `isScrollEnabled` to `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `UIScrollView`, `clipsToBounds` is set to `true` by default. I think this so that its subviews disappear as they get scrolled beyond its bounds. I guess `UITextView` just inherits this setting.

I think that's OK, but I'd suggest adding the subview to the superview of your `UITextView` instead.